# Run macro multiple lines

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that was written to work on one row.  I want to run this macro on all the rows that are highlighted instead.

Is there a way to loop between the selected rows and run the macro for each one.

Because of company policy I cannot show the entire macro, but it basically takes the values in a row in excel and populates it into a word template.  Here is the start of the macro:

```
Sub OpenForm()
With Selection
    Dim pappWord As Object
    Dim docWord As Object
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim TodayDate As String
    Dim Path As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    TodayDate = Format(Date, "mmmm d, yyyy")
    Path = wb.Path & "\MAF Template.dot"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

     'Create a new Word Session
    Set pappWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

     'Open document in word
    Set docWord = pappWord.Documents.Add(Path)
    'Blank for Qty
    docWord.FormFields("Text38").Result = Range(ActiveCell.EntireRow.Address)(1, 2) 'Part of System (System ID)
```

....it populates more fields and ends with:

```
    With pappWord
        .Visible = True
        .ActiveWindow.WindowState = 0
        .Activate
    End With


     'Release the Word object to save memory and exit macro
ErrorExit:
    Set pappWord = Nothing
    Exit Sub

     'Error Handling routine
ErrorHandler:
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & "; There is a problem"
        If Not pappWord Is Nothing Then
            pappWord.Quit False
        End If
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

So it works for a single excel row, instead of running this for every row, I want to select some rows and run the macro through all of them.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes - exactly how would depend on your macro, so if you update your question with your existing code I'm sure you'll get suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there a way to loop between the selected rows and run the macro for each one?  A: Yes.  For example, Google for "VBAScript cell range".  for example:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308
- http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referring_to_ranges_in_your_vba_code/
- http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-programming-range-excel-vba.html

'Hope that helps ... at least a little.

You'd have to post some code and explain more about your application before we could help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range

Set a = Selection

For Each b In a.Rows

    b.Value = "xpto"
    //your code will here...but only seeing your code to be more precise

Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post.  This sort of worked, but it used the data from the first row and repeated it x times.

Comment: it didn't work correctly though, it runs the macro the correct number of times (the number of highlighted rows), but it uses the data from the first row only, and doesn't grab the data from the others.